# Dificuldades com A logica

Tags: java, autenticação, lógica

Bem o cenário é o seguinte estou tentando desenvolver um ponto eletrônico através da minha aplicação porem travei na lógica de autenticação das datas e horas de trabalho seguinte na lógica que tenho no momento ele autentica a data de forma correta porem quando vai autenticar a entrada ao invés de autenticar o valor na mesma linha ou seja usando o mesmo id ele autentica em uma outra linha
ele criar um novo registro espero que alguém possa me ajudar com essa questão segue a lógica que estou desenvolvendo.

```
List<Folha> findDateUser = folhaService.findByDateAndUser(data, usuario.getId());

    for (Folha listaCompleta : findDateUser) {

        if (listaCompleta.getData() == null) {

            listaCompleta.getIdFolha();
            listaCompleta.setData(data);
            listaCompleta.setUsuario(usuario);
            folhaDAO.persistir(listaCompleta);

        } else if (listaCompleta.getData() != null) {

            listaCompleta.getIdFolha();
            listaCompleta.setData(data);
            listaCompleta.setEntrada(entrada);
            listaCompleta.setUsuario(usuario);

            folhaDAO.update(listaCompleta);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Só com o postado acho difícil ajudar, só posso dizer que esse trecho pode ser bastante simplicado.

Comment: o que posso fazer ai para simplificar essa logica ?